# how to expose ports using docker for asp.net core

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose, ports, windows-server-2016

I generated a docker file. This is ok and all. but I want the ports to be exposed for the application.
I added the ports part to the docker file below.

Unfortunately this doesn't work..

I'm using Windows Server 2016 Datacenter. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
version: '3'

services:
  project:
    image: subproject
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Janssen1877.WarehouseAPI\Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
```

**EDIT**

I found out that the port is configured in the docker-compose.override.yml file.
It actually runs on my windows 10 development environment. it's also reachable from my other computers.

On the windows server 2016 it also run's but only locally. I can't find a way to expose the ports even though I use ports: 44323:80 in the override file.

So now the main question is shifted into finding why Windows Server 2016 doesn't bind the port to it's own IP

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

Following the examples placed at [docs.docker.com](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/#step-3-define-services-in-a-compose-file) I think you should set the ports like:

```
ports:
 - "5432:5432"
```

Instead of

```
ports:
 - 5432:5432
```

Comment: This is not the problem. Both formats are acceptable.

Comment: Unfortunately the error code stays the same. I used the format without quotes in a different project and it worked there. I think both formats are acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

The ports must be

```
- "5432:5432"
```

What is the error message?